# Strange random values in OpenTK.Matrix4

Tags: c#, matrix, opentk

I am trying to build a modelview matrix for a project using OpenTK's Matrix4 class. I am trying to build a translation matrix, but the matrix keeps setting random values.
Here is a screenshot of the console:
[image: Console dump]

And here is the code im using to build it:

```
private static Matrix4 CreateModelview(Rectangle dst)
        {
            var scale = Matrix4.CreateScale(dst.Size.X, dst.Size.Y, 1.0f);
            var translation = new Matrix4();

            translation[0, 0] = 1f;
            translation[1, 1] = 1f;
            translation[2, 2] = 1f;
            translation[3, 3] = 1f;
            translation[3, 0] = dst.Position.X;
            translation[3, 1] = dst.Position.Y;
            translation[0, 3] = 0f;
            translation[1, 3] = 0f;

            Console.WriteLine("Translation:");
            Console.WriteLine(translation);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Scale:");
            Console.WriteLine(scale);
            Console.WriteLine();
            var modelview = scale * translation;

            return modelview;
        }
```

I tried the build in static function Matrix4f.CreateTranslation with the same result.

Comment: What rectangles have you put in and what did you expect?

Comment: I just solved it myself, it was a combination of me flipping rows and coulumns. Im sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it myself, it was a combination of me flipping rows and columns and uploading it wrong to my uniform buffer.